# meta tag "wb:op" what is this?

Tags: html, tags, meta

I've been working on a certain webpage for years now learning as I go..

I have this meta tag that I can't seem to find any information on, like what it is!

```
<meta name="wb:op" content="*censored buncha random numbers*">
```

I censored the numbers just because I don't know what they belong to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the archive of n00b questions.. it looks like some sort of automatic residual wordpress plugin meta tag put in by accidentally installing something via my hosting's cPanel.

Cheers everybody.